# What is the difference between running a docker dotnet console app through Visual Studio and Docker Run?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, visual-studio

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I am relatively new to Docker and this may simply be a misunderstanding on my part.

I have a dotnet 6 console app that is being deployed to Docker. When I run this via the Visual Studio Docker launch setting, it works fine, I can see the logs in Docker. However, if I go to the image in Docker Desktop, and launch it using the Run option, I don't see any logs, and as far as I can tell, the app does not actually run at all.

So what is the difference between the two ways of launching the container? Apart from that one works and one doesn't?!

I have tried supplying some of the same environment variable arguments that Visual Studio puts in it's own Docker Run command, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Update: here is the dockerfile that I can reproduce the problem on - it's just the default one that VS generates when you Add Docker Support:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj", "ConsoleApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp1"
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

The app itself is just the boiler plate that gets created when you ask VS to add a new console app.
If I run through Visual Studio, it does indeed print "Hello, World!" - however, if I use the Run option against the Image in Docker Desktop, or I use Docker Run, the container spins up but there's nothing in the logs.

This happens on 2 different computers.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with the .net core application and have invested more than 5 hours figuring this out and can not find any proper answer to this question, help is needed ....

Answer (score 0):

You've provided very little information about your project, so it's hard to say what is wrong. In general, running a console app in a container is very similar to running it outside the container.

If you take the following Dockerfile that creates a new console app and builds it

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet new console -o . --name myapp
RUN dotnet publish -o /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
CMD ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

you can then build and run it using

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test
```

and it'll print out "Hello, World!" as it should.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I didn't provide any further details of the project because my question was more of a general question about what Visual Studio and Docker Run does differently, since it produces different results. Additionally, I have tried this with different projects and the same thing happens, which has led me to believe that this is common to dotnet console apps in general.

Comment: Stack Overflow is much more geared towards specific questions about specific problems so you'll have better luck if you provide a reproducible example with an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Kilian, I've added a little more detail now.